# Avoid switch in calculator? - Java

Tags: java, switch-statement

I've just started out on Java and I made a calculator with a **GUI** which includes this part of code:

```
 private void Decider(char c){
    switch (c){
        case '+':
            CalculatorGui.add.operate();
            break;
        case '-':
            CalculatorGui.sub.operate();
            break;`
        case '*':
            CalculatorGui.mul.operate();
            break;
        case '/':
            CalculatorGui.div.operate();
            break;
        default:
            System.out.printf("Invalid\n");
            break;

    }
}
```

The `char c` given depends on which button the user clicks on the interface. If he clicks `+` we get a `+` if he clicks `-` we get `-` etc. Each time I call the method I need from 4 other classes I've made.

My question is: Is there a way to avoid the switch statement?

I suppose I could make one class with one method and depending on what we pass it will do the proper operation. But then I'll have to make a switch statement in there so this leads nowhere.

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you want to avoid using a switch? Anyway, if you are using a gui (as it seems to be) you can attach a specific listener to the operation button. So you can attach 4 different listeners to the `+`, `-`, `*`, `/` buttons and they will be called accordingly, without the need for a switch statement. If you still want to use the character and switch on it, you could also use a `Map` with `+`, `-`, `*`, `/` as keys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can prepare a map of `Runnable`:

```
Map<Character, Runnable> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put('+', () -> CalculatorGui.add.operate());
map.put('-', () -> CalculatorGui.sub.operate());
map.put('*', () -> CalculatorGui.mul.operate());
map.put('/', () -> CalculatorGui.div.operate());
```

And then use that map to perform the corresponding action, or the default action:

```
map.getOrDefault(c, () -> System.out.println("Invalid")).run();
```

Comment: Why Runnable? Isn't this about binary operators that are BiFunctions : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/BiFunction.html

Comment: @DavidSoroko because the pasted code has void static method calls that take no arguments. If the posted code had calls that take 2 parameters and returned a value, then `BiFunction` would be a good fit. It's also possible that OP should reorganize his code completely, but we haven't seen what else is there, and I want to avoid guesswork and speculation.

Comment: You are right, but there is no avoiding guessing. I suppose that the only way op code could make sense is when the actual operands are instance variables in the class containing Decider.